# Python login screen - How to validate the password from a json file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, authentication

I am writing a login screen that asks for user name and password. Once I have this screen working correctly, I plan on adding it to the start of a larger program I am working on.

The problem I am having currently is that I have been unable to validate a password for a *specific* user. Right now, the program will check if a username already exists, if it does then it will check if the password exists. The problem is that someone could enter another username and there own password and then login to someone else's account. Security isn't a huge deal for my program (I"m just making a duolingo type language app) but this is a pretty obvious problem that I'd like to figure out how to resolve.

```
from tkinter import *
import json
class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        master.title("Login")

        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_username.focus()     #This sets the focus to the username entry box
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.login_button = Button(self, text="Login", command=self.Login)
        self.login_button.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.grid()

    def Login(self):
        current_info = open ("C:\\LearningArabic\\LiblibArriby\\Usernames\\usernames.json").read()

        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        if username in current_info:
            print("Test")
            if password in current_info:
                print("Now we're talking")
            else:
                print("Well, you're trying")
        else:       #This section appends the new username and password combo to the json file
            usr = {username: password}
            with open("C:\\LearningArabic\\LiblibArriby\\Usernames\\usernames.json") as a:
                data = json.load(a)

            data.update(usr)

            with open("C:\\LearningArabic\\LiblibArriby\\Usernames\\usernames.json", "w") as a:
                json.dump(data, a)
root = Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated and if there are other comments on the code please don't hold back. I want to learn - not just get the answer!

Comment: Just checking; this is a toy example, right? You're not storing passwords in a JSON for anything vaguely important?

Comment: you probably want to be hashing your password, see something like: https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @roganjosh, Yes - the passwords stored here aren't for anything "important". In fact, I almost skipped passwords completely and just used usernames but I thought it would be good for me to learn a little more this way.

Comment: @SamMason, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keeping your current file format, I'd just do something like:

```
PATH_USERNAMES = "C:/LearningArabic/LiblibArriby/Usernames/usernames.json"

with open(PATH_USERNAMES) as fd:
  current_info = json.load(fd)

username = self.entry_username.get()
password = self.entry_password.get()

if username in current_info:
  saved_password = current_info.get(username, '')
  if password == saved_password:
    print("Password OK")
```

but strongly suggest you save the password hashed and alter the validation appropriately…

Comment: I gave this a try but got the 
saved_password = current_info.get(username, '')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Any thoughst?

Comment: you want to be using `json.dump` to get the object back out of the file, rather than `read()`ing it

Comment: json.dump not json.load? Wouldn't I wan't to load the file so I could then check the contents?

Comment: yes, you're right…  sorry, concentrating on other things!

Comment: Ahh, that does it. Thanks for the quick tip! And I'll definitely look into hashing.

Comment: if you're new to software stuff I'd suggest looking into relational databases as well.  they make saving/loading data much easier.  Python comes with SQLite and provides a relatively nice package for interacting with it